# SD card showing up in `dmesg` but not elsewhere

Tags: mount, sd-card, inspiron, 19.04

I am trying to mount an SD card using built-in reader on my Dell Inspiron 7570 running Ubuntu 19.04.

When I insert the card, `dmesg` says:

```
$ dmesg
[...]
[  202.433303] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  202.592161] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0177, bcdDevice=77.11
[  202.592167] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  202.592171] usb 1-6: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  202.592174] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Generic
[  202.592176] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 20121112761000000
[  202.597365] ums-realtek 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  202.605549] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[  203.615414] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC/MS PRO    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  203.616345] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  210.871920] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  214.498456] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

Unfortunately the drive does not appear anywhere (i.e. `# fdisk -l`).

Trying to find it I realised that my card reader is not visible in `lsusb` (listing below), so I do not understand why the system reacts on inserting the card.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6a06 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The SD card is working under Windows.

How can I access it from Ubuntu?
Do you think there are drivers required to make it working?

### More information as requested by @Thomas:

```
$ grep -H . /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/*
/sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/auto_delink_en:1
/sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/enable_mmc:1
/sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/ss_delay:50
/sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/ss_en:1
```

Comment: According to `dmesg` it got */dev/sdc* assigned. Does `sudo lsblk` show the SD card? If so, you could try to mount it with `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sdcard; sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: Since 19.04, my built-in card reader ceased to operate, and I use a SD-to-USB reader to view the card now.  I find that it actually works a little better, and have not tried to investigate

Comment: Thanks for you reply, @Thomas. `lsblk` lists multiple `loopX` devices and trees for `sda` and `sdb` which are the build-in SSD and HDD drives.

Comment: @Thomas, I had a feeling the `[sdc]` in `dmesg` meand the device, so I tried mounting it before. Unortunately it says the special device `/dev/sdc` does not exist.

Comment: Just reviewed your question and saw `usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5` which happens 4 seconds after `/dev/sdc` is assigned. It seems the SD card reader gets detached from USB.

Comment: This might be a misbehaving *selective suspend* / *autosuspend*. Could you add the output of `grep -H . /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/*`. You also could try to `sudo echo 0 > /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/ss_en` and/or `sudo echo /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/auto_delink_en`. This depends on the version of the driver and I do not have a 19.04 right now to double check. But the `grep` command should reveal things.

Comment: @Thomas, I added the output in the main question.

Comment: Try to `sudo echo 0 > /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/ss_en` and/or `sudo echo /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/auto_delink_en` and attach your SD card afterwards.

Comment: @Thomas, both `ss_en` and `auto_delink_en` existed and were set to 1. I changed both to 0, and **now it works**. `dmesg` shows some problems with partition table, so it still doesn't mount, but when I plug the card, a message is shown as expected. This seems to be a solution. Could you add an answer so that I can accept it? -I cannot upvote your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to a misbehaving *auto suspend* function of the `ums_realtek` driver.

From the output of `dmesg` of the question one can see that the device gets detached again 4 seconds after the SD card is assigned a device name.

```
[  210.871920] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  214.498456] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

A simple fix during runtime is to disable the *auto suspend* function of the `ums_realtek` driver. Not sure if both are needed or if just one does the trick. Maybe @MaciekS can do further testing on this.

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/ss_en  
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/ums_realtek/parameters/auto_delink_en
```

To make these settings reboot resistant, one has to create a file.

```
# sudo su
# cat > /etc/modprobe.d/ums_realtek.conf << 'UMS'
options ums_realtek ss_en=0
options ums_realtek auto_delink_en=0
UMS
```

Since I do not have a Realtek based SD card reader nor a Ubuntu 19.04 I cannot further debug this.
It also might be that a user space program or daemon like power saving things is triggering this and the problem is solved by removing the possibility to suspend USB devices.

Comment: In my case it worked only when both `ss_en` and `auto_delink_en` were set to 0.

Comment: @charles-green, could you check whether this works for you as well?

Comment: @MaciekS: just noticed I have a typo in the `echo` commands. So the `auto_delink_en` did not get changed if you just copy/pasted that and it might be sufficient to just put ss_en to 0.

Comment: I changed the values in the files to zeros using an editor, as I realised one of them doesn't do much and wanted to see what's inside the files. I forgot to mention the commands are wrong. Sorry.

Comment: This used to work for me for some time, but today I tried mounting my SD card and facing exactly tse same issue as in the original question. The fix that worked before does not help anymore. Did anything change in Ubuntu?